# nodejs start react-app client

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've made a web app using `create-react-app` which works fine, and I usually run it using `npm start` but now I have to deploy it and make it work with nodejs `forever` module.

If I do `node src/index.js` it will give a syntax error and to fix this I used babel to transpile `es6` to `es5`, but again I get the following syntax error when importing the css file:

```
/client/src/stylesheets/menu.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { header {
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "date-diff": "^0.1.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.12",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "validator": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-with-stylus start src/stylesheets/menu.styl",
    "build": "react-scripts-with-stylus build src/stylesheets/menu.styl",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "create-react-app-stylus": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to deploy it, you should make a build, not run your application directly.

Comment: How can I make a build? This is my first react app and any information would help me a lot... I'm trying to deploy it to digital ocean

Comment: run `npm run build` and it will generate build files into a new folder.

Comment: Done. These are the next steps?   `npm install -g serve`
  `serve -s build`

Comment: You should not try to run the application with npm at all. You should copy all the files from the build folder into the root of your server and when a user opens the page it will be shown index.html file.

Comment: Now every time I change my client code I also have to do `npm run build` in order to push them to production ... is this correct?

Comment: Yes if your code has changed and is ready for production you can rebuild it, or you can automate this process with some CI tool.

Comment: I have one last question...is it a good practice to have both the react client files and the react build folder on a git repository?

Comment: You should only have React client files on your Git repository, build files should be generated during the build process on your server.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the answer to this question:

- If you need to deploy it, you should make a build, not run your application directly.
- run `npm run build` and it will generate build files into a new folder.
- You should not try to run the application with npm at all. You should copy all the files from the build folder into the root of your server and when a user opens the page it will be shown index.html file.
- If your code has changed and is ready for production you can rebuild it, or you can automate this process with some CI tool.
- You should only have React client files on your Git repository, build files should be generated during the build process on your server.